# Cartesian Coordinates to Geo Position

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, geodesy

Having $(lat, lon)$ I used the following formulae to convert it to Cartesian
\begin{align}
x & = R \cos(lat) \cos(lon)\\
y &= R \cos(lat) \sin(lon) 
\end{align}

Now, I need to convert ***x,y*** back to ***latitude, longitude***.

I need the solution for the inversion formulae

Comment: You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates) page out.

Comment: Divide and conquer.  But subtract also.

Comment: Hint $\cos^2(lon)+\sin^2(lon)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the longitude by taking $\arctan \frac yx$ and correcting for the quadrant.  If you have Atan2 available it will take care of the quadrant.  Then you can find the $\cos$ and $\sin$ of that and divide them out.  Now you just need an $\arccos$ to get there.